# How do I install the latest Nvidia drivers automatically?

Tags: nvidia

There are a bunch of `nvidias-drivers-*` packages that are for different versions

```
nvidia-driver-390/eoan 390.129-0ubuntu2 amd64
  NVIDIA driver metapackage

nvidia-driver-418/eoan 430.50-0ubuntu2 amd64
  Transitional package for nvidia-driver-430

nvidia-driver-430/eoan 430.50-0ubuntu2 amd64
  NVIDIA driver metapackage

nvidia-driver-435/eoan 435.21-0ubuntu2 amd64
```

How do I install just the latest one without having to look for the biggest number by hand?

Answer (score 5):

You don't always want to install the latest proprietary graphics driver. You want to install the latest driver that is compatible with the computer's hardware. Ubuntu has a built-in ubuntu-drivers program that can decide automatically which proprietary graphics driver to install, and streamlines the installation of Nvidia drivers. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install   
sudo reboot
```

The `install` option of `ubuntu-drivers` installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.

Comment: `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` is marked as deprecated

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The results of `ubuntu-drivers -h` show: `autoinstall  Deprecated, please use "install" instead`. The `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` command works the same as `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` on my computer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following command to *only* install the correct Nvidia driver for your system without installing other proprietary drivers.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers --gpgpu autoinstall nvidia
```

Also please note @Boris's alternative suggestion in the comments to use:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers --gpgpu install nvidia
```

The help for the `ubuntu-drivers` command indicates that `autoinstall` is now deprecated.

```
ubuntu-drivers --help
  autoinstall  Deprecated, please use "install" instead
```

Comment: The real command that worked for me was `sudo ubuntu-drivers --gpgpu install nvidia` but [my edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1120598) was rejected for "deviating from the original intent of the post".

Comment: Boris, your suggestion seems reasonable. I added it to the answer so people have a choice which command they want to use.