# Hw to install nvidia drivers for Ubuntu sever 20.04 without installing the gui

Tags: server, nvidia

I have a multi-purpose server and I would like to have it run F@H for the time being and I can't get it to detect the GPU so I'm trying to install the correct drivers. But I either go in Dependency hell or it installs gnome and everything with that

I just want to install the drivers and that's it

If anyone can help me with that problem would be nice

System specs:

- OS: ubuntu 20.04 lts X86_64
- Kernel:5.4.0-26-generic
- CPU: AMD Phenom II X6 1075T (6) @ 3.000GHz
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960
- RAM: 8GB

Comment: What steps did you take in both cases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the latest Nvidia drivers automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195996/how-do-i-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-automatically)

Comment: Fatih Baltacı: using your recommmendation you also install the whole X11 which is not good for server. Do you know how to avoid it and still install the driver with CUDA?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well, and have found a solution. Using the `--no-install-recommends` flag seems to install the driver without the gnome environment.

Full command:
`sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends nvidia-driver-<version>`

Answer (score 0):

- You can search available nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt search nvidia-driver
```

[image: output]

- Install nvidia-driver-440 package:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440
```

Comment: Just running `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-<version>` does not answer the question. This command installs the nvidia driver along with the gnome desktop environment bloat, which TIBTHINK specifically said they didn't want